# Create merged tables in R

Tags: r

I have some data in multiple large data tables in R. I wish to merge and produce counts of various variables.

I can produce the counts within individual tables easily using the 'table' command, but I have not yet figured out the economical (preferably base R, one liner) command to then produce combined counts.

```
aaa<-table(MyData1$MyVar)
bbb<-table(MyData2$MyVar)

> aaa
Dogs     3
Cats     4
Horses   1
Sheep    2
Giraffes 3

> bbb
Dogs     27
Cats      1
Sheep     2
Ocelots   1
```

Desired Output:

```
Dogs     30
Cats      5
Horses    1
Sheep     4
Giraffes  3
Ocelots   1
```

I am sure there is a straightforward Base R way to do this I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

First merge/concatenate your input, then apply table to it.

```
table(c(MyData1$MyVar, MyData2$MyVar))
```

You may run into issue if MyVar is a factor and its levels are different in MyData1 and MyData2. In this case, just lookup how to merge factor variables.

**EDIT**: if that doesn't suit your need, I suggest the following:

Merge the levels of all "MyVar" throughout all your "MyDatai" tables (from your example, I assume that it makes sense to do this).

```
total_levels <- unique(c(levels(MyData1$MyVar), levels(MyData2$MyVar)))

MyData1$MyVar <- factor(MyData1$MyVar, levels=total_levels)
MyData2$MyVar <- factor(MyData1$MyVar, levels=total_levels)
```

Obviously you will need wrap this into an apply-like function if you have around 100 data.frames.

Note that this is a one-time preprocessing operation, so I think it's ok if it is a bit costly. Ideally you can integrate it upstream when you generate/load the data.

At this point, all your "MyVar" have the same levels (but are still the same in terms of content of course). Now the good thing is, since `table` works with the levels, all your tables will have the same entries:

```
aaa<-table(MyData1$MyVar)
bbb<-table(MyData2$MyVar)

> aaa
Dogs     3
Cats     4
Horses   1
Sheep    2
Giraffes 3
Ocelot   0

> bbb
Dogs     27
Cats      1
Horses    0
Sheep     2
Giraffes  0
Ocelots   1
```

And you can just sum them with `aaa+bbb` or `sum` if you have a lot. Addition of vectors is lightning fast :)

Comment: Thanks - think this will work but it means bumping up against R memory limitations potentially - my idea is to avoid that if possible by avoiding large table joins.

Comment: addendium - (I appreciate it's only joining one var here, but there are potentially a few hundred large(ish) tables to hold in order just to join the vars, so in my use case I think it would cause an issue (fwiw one table alone is likely 20k-100k rows, 10-30 variables or thereabouts).

Comment: I think your dataset is still small enough to simply merge the columns (as you say, it's a one variable merge), but anyway I've edited a solution you may find more appropriate, still using only base R.

Answer (score 2):

Base package:

```
aggregate(V2 ~ V1, data = rbind(df1, df2), FUN = sum)
```

dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
rbind(df1, df2) %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(V2 = sum(V2))
```

Output:

```
        V1 V2
1     Cats  5
2     Dogs 30
3 Giraffes  3
4   Horses  1
5    Sheep  4
6  Ocelots  1
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("Cats", 
"Dogs", "Giraffes", "Horses", "Sheep"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Cats", 
"Dogs", "Ocelots", "Sheep"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(27L, 1L, 
2L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks - not currently using dplyr (although Hadley's work is fantastic). Guessing %>% is equivalent to unix pipe.

Comment: @Pascoe I'm not familiar with Unix but I think you are right. It is mentioned in the [vignette of magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) . The pipe %>% operator was introduced by the `magrittr` package and `dplyr` benefits from it.

Comment: @Pascoe By the way, has my base package answer solved your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: HI, for some reason getting error "Number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg1) when I try the base package approach. I'm sure it's something silly I am doing. But as things stand haven't yet managed to replicate your result.

Comment: @Pascoe You can replicate my results by copying the code under Data, df1, df2. Because you use `table` you get the class table instead of a data frame. If you post the result of dput(MyData1) and dput(MyData2), your actual data frames, we could get the desired output more easily.